# Testing whether a gmail user has previously communicated with a given email

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

An app that I'm developing needs to test whether, for a given email address, the user has previously sent or received email from the address on the user's gmail account. However, this should be done without the app having the credentials to the google account, and without allowing the app to get any other information other than a true/false result to such a query.

How can this be achieved?

The solution should, if at all possible, use some existing google service to minimize or even completely avoid setting up my own server app to facilitate this.

An initial idea I had for this: use a google apps script that will get an authorization by the user to access email, and then scan all emails to collect the set of unique recipients and senders. Then, those emails will be saved in such a way that some URL handler can practically instantly respond to a query about whether or not a specific email exists in this set.

Comment: Your idea is not practical. First it involves storing all the user data somewhere else, which is much worse that the saved tokena you are trying to avoid. Plus it will miss all new emails since your 'backup' among other problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's a better architecture to have the app query Gmail directly for this information, instead of using an Apps Script web app as an intermediary. The new Gmail API's [`Users.messages.list()`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) method allows you to search for messages, and the `q` parameter takes the same types of queries that the Gmail UI supports, such as "to:person@example.com". Additionally there is a read-only scope supported by the API, so that users can feel more comfortable with the app gaining access to their inbox.